# How do you name nodes/vertices with this type of code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) \foreach \i in {5}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,\i}{ -- ++(360/\i*\j:2) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Note: Figure not drawn to scale.}
\end{figure}
```

The code above creates a regular pentagon, but I am lost as to how to name the nodes/vertices as A, B, C, D, and E. Do I have to manually calculate the coordinates or is there a better way to go about naming the vertices?

The end result I am aiming for looks something like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [sane_tikz](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz) to generate TikZ figures by writing Python code. You can change the constants to regenerate the figure slightly differently.

[image]

Python sane_tikz code for the figure:

```
import sane_tikz as stz
import formatting as fmt

label_spacing = 0.25
pentagon_radius = 1.2
x_axis_length = 4.0
y_axis_length = 3.0
extra_length = 0.4
a_circle_radius = 0.1
s_fmt = fmt.arrow_heads("end")
f_fmt = fmt.line_and_fill_colors('black', 'black')

cs = [
    stz.coords_on_circle([0, 0], pentagon_radius, 90.0 + i * (360.0 / 5))
    for i in range(5)
]
e = stz.closed_path(cs)

origin_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(cs[2], -1.0)
x_end_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(origin_cs, x_axis_length)
y_end_cs = stz.translate_coords_vertically(origin_cs, y_axis_length)
x_start_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(origin_cs, -extra_length)
y_start_cs = stz.translate_coords_vertically(origin_cs, -extra_length)
x_label_cs = stz.translate_coords_vertically(x_end_cs, -label_spacing)
y_label_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(y_end_cs, -label_spacing)
origin_label_cs = stz.translate_coords_diagonally(origin_cs, -label_spacing)

axes = [
    stz.line_segment(x_start_cs, x_end_cs, s_fmt),
    stz.line_segment(y_start_cs, y_end_cs, s_fmt)
]

labels = [
    stz.latex([cs[0][0], cs[0][1] + label_spacing], "$C$"),
    stz.latex([cs[1][0] - label_spacing, cs[1][1]], "$B$"),
    stz.latex([cs[2][0], cs[2][1] - 1.25 * label_spacing], "$A(1, 0)$"),
    stz.latex([cs[3][0], cs[3][1] - 1.25 * label_spacing], "$E$"),
    stz.latex([cs[4][0] + label_spacing, cs[4][1]], "$D$"),
    stz.circle(cs[2], a_circle_radius, f_fmt),
    stz.latex(x_label_cs, "$x$"),
    stz.latex(y_label_cs, "$y$"),
    stz.latex(origin_label_cs, "$O$"),
]

stz.draw_to_tikz_standalone([e, labels, axes], "example.tex")
```

Generated TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[] (0.000000, 1.200000) -- (-1.141268, 0.370820) -- (-0.705342, -0.970820) -- (0.705342, -0.970820) -- (1.141268, 0.370820) -- cycle;
\node[] at (0.000000,1.450000) {$C$};
\node[] at (-1.391268,0.370820) {$B$};
\node[] at (-0.705342,-1.283320) {$A(1, 0)$};
\node[] at (0.705342,-1.283320) {$E$};
\node[] at (1.391268,0.370820) {$D$};
\draw[fill=black, draw=black] (-0.705342, -0.970820) circle (0.100000);
\node[] at (2.294658,-1.220820) {$x$};
\node[] at (-1.955342,2.029180) {$y$};
\node[] at (-1.955342,-1.220820) {$O$};
\draw[-latex] (-2.105342, -0.970820) -- (2.294658, -0.970820);
\draw[-latex] (-1.705342, -1.370820) -- (-1.705342, 2.029180);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this. You can introduce a counter and use `\Alph`, or use `{A,...,E}` in a foreach loop. It really depends on what you ultimately want to do with this.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{icheat}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) foreach \i in {5}
  {foreach \j in {1,...,\i}{ -- ++(360/\i*\j:2) 
  coordinate[label={[anchor=\j*360/\i+124]\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myj}{1+Mod(4-\j,\i)}%
  \setcounter{icheat}{\myj}\Alph{icheat}}]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Note: Figure not drawn to scale.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,minimum size=3.5cm,draw,
xscale=-1,rotate=72*3](5gon){};
\path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {A,...,E} {
(5gon.center) -- (5gon.corner \X) node[pos=1.1]{\Y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Note: Figure not drawn to scale.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]